# Is it a good play for a runner on third coming home when a hitter hit a ground ball to second base?

Tags: baseball

When a hitter hits a short ground ball to second base, should a runner on third stay at the base or run home?

Comment: What's the game situation? (score, innings, anyone else on base, outs, count)

Comment: loosing 8:6, 4th inning, only runner on third, no outs

Comment: Personally early in the game and no outs I'd hold the runner. You have two more shots to get him in with a hit, and one more try to get him in with a sac fly. If the score were turned the other way and I was up I'd be tempted to safety squeeze. But I have no stats to back any of this up, so this stays a comment and not an answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks James. Sounds like holding it makes more sense.

Comment: "loosing 8:6, 4th inning, only runner on third, no outs" => stay on third unless you are 100% sure of scoring or unless weak batters are coming up (batters with many strikeouts for example)

Comment: It also depends on how deep the infield is playing, although when you say "short ground ball", that sounds like the ball is expected to be fielded quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two outs: YES in almost all situations.

With less than two outs:

- Last inning / trailing by two or more: NO. You need two points, don't take any risk
- Last inning / one out / on-deck batter is weak / trailing by one, tied game or winning by a few runs: YES. You must evaluate your chance of being safe at home vs a weak batter hitting a hit against a closer.
- Other cases: it depends. Take these factors into account: the score, number of outs, on-deck batter, pitcher, speed of runners, fielding ability / defense positioning.

I always tell my teammates to think of their play in advance (as a runner or as a fielder).